# Connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I had someone set up my server, but we had a falling out and that's no longer an option. My computer can't even seem to detect my mouse and it says it can't connect to the internet. I can't do my blogs or upload my podcast until I get this web site working again. I also don't really know anything about computers at the highly technical level. What do I do?

Comment: Solving this problem with you will require a long series of questions and answers, many of which will require you to do things and report back. Since your need appears to be urgent, I suggest you Google for Ubuntu or Linux support businesses in your area. Local user groups are another option. What a knowledgeable person can do in an hour onsite could take days to lead you through online.